# Country name in SVG map

Tags: dictionary, svg, mapping

What would be the right way to store country name in SVG file? I use id to store country codes, but it would be very useful to have country names attached to the paths too.

Acoarding to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/extend.html) article, I should use some custom namespace for country names? Or is there some attribute which is usually used? I checked some publicly available SVG maps and could't find any keeping country names.

Comment: You can use *<text>* . Check this out http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Map_of_USA_with_state_names.svg and view source!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element can contain `<desc>` and `<title>` elements which [are used exactly for describing the shape that is drawn](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#DescriptionAndTitleElements). You should use one of those.

If you want a semantic description that can be seen by people/software looking inside the file, or maybe manipulate it with JavaScript to display it to the user, select, filter, or whatever, then you should use the `<desc>` element.

The `<title>` element, on the other hand, will be displayed to the user when hovering over it, just like the equivalent `title` attribute in HTML. Note that the title must be the first child element to behave correctly as a tooltip.